# updateDisplayName() not working after running createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a future method in a `AuthService` class to create new users with the inbuilt function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, but right after that I am trying to update the display name of that `User? user` but this never updates.

```dart
Future regEmailPass(String email, String password, String? username) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User? user = result.user;
      await user?.updateDisplayName(username);

      UserInApp? userInApp = _userFromFireBaseUser(user);
      await DatabaseService(user: userInApp).firstTimeCreateDB(username!);
      return userInApp;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I even tried using the `await user.reload()` or double checking if my `user` was `null` in the first place, but in every situation, the `displayName` was set to `null` in the firestore database.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9065. I posted this issue in github too

Comment: What do you have in `result.user` after `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is completed?